# Hooks don't support the second callback argument

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm writing some code in React Native to get the users location in a Google Map, but I'm getting an error, stating that:

> State updates from the `useState()` and `useReducer()` Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with `useEffect()`.

The code is from an video on YouTube. It's posted in 2019, so maybe something have have changed after that. Can somebody point in me in the right direction?

```
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.0",
"react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.2.0",
"react-native-maps": "0.28.0"
```

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';

const region = {
  latitude: null,
  longitude: null,
  latitudeDelta: 0.0222,
  longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
};

const App = () => {
  const [currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = useState(region);

  useEffect(() => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      const { longitude, latitude } = position.coords;
      setCurrentPosition(
        {
          ...currentPosition,
          latitude,
          longitude,
        },
        (error) => alert(error.message),
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
      );
    });
  }, []);

  return currentPosition.latitude ? (
    <MapView
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
      showsUserLocation
      initialRegion={currentPosition}
    />
  ) : (
    <ActivityIndicator style={{ flex: 1 }} animating size="large" />
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Looks like the second callback and the object after it should be in the call to `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition`, not in the call to `setCurrentPosition`.

Comment: The `setCurrentPosition` function only takes a single object (the way you have set it up here) so those two other arguments you have passed in `(error) => alert(error.message)` and `{ enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }` causing that warning.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out.